# Getting a TLS certificate for Exim and Dovecot that works with gmail

Tags: server, gmail, mail

I have a CentOS 7 server that is running Exim and Dovecot for communicating on SMTP and POP3 ports. I want to configure them to use TLS to encrypt all data. I have already figured how to change the config files of Exim and Dovecot, but there is one problem: the certificates I intended to use are self-signed and it seems that gmail does not accept SSL certificates that are self-signed.

Now I want to buy a DV SSHL certificate from a trusted authority, but I don't know which subdomain I should buy it for. My DNS records include an MX record that says "10 mail" and then it is assigned to the IP address of my server. I don't know what 10 means there, but I suppose that means mail.domain.tld is the address of my mail server. Right?

So, here are my questions:

1. Should I get a certificate for mail.domain.tld?
2. Can I use my certificate for domain.tld which has been issued by a trusted authority?
3. Can I get a certificate for an IP address instead of a FQDN? Will that work with gmail too?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but wanted to point out that the 10 is the MX record "priority". More info: https://serverfault.com/questions/178041/mx-record-priorities

Comment: Another thing to note is that "regular" DV certificates don't work for email, you need to get a special "email" certificate from a CA that's set up to sign those.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister  Thanks. Do you happen to know what kind of certificate I should buy, if not a regular DV certificate? Should it be an EV certificate? There are lots of names out there for SSL certificates and they cost differently. So, I'm really confused.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that neither a standard DV nor standard EV cert will work. It has to be a different kind of cert that's specifically for stuff like email, not for a website. I would be searching for "email ssl certificate" rather than just "ssl certificate".